# How to register a UWP app as share recipient for camera snapshot

Tags: c#, uwp, share, screen-capture

In Windows 10, when I hit e.g. SHIFT + WIN + S I can take a screenshot of my screen.
In other cases I have my webcam that can take a picture, and so on.
All those scenarios have the feature to "Share" the captured image to another app, e.g. Mail, OneNote, etc.

I would like to register my own UWP app to be the recipient of such Share, so that the user can manipulate the captured image in my UWP app.

Is there a way to configure my UWP app to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure my UWP app to do this?

Yes, you could make your UWP app a receiver when you want to share some content from other apps.

1. Declare your app as a share target. Open the **manifest** file. Find the **Declarations** tab, then choose **Share Target** from the Available Declarations list, and then select Add.
2. Set the **file types and formats** based on your requirements in the Declarations. For example, if you need to receive a screenshot, you will need to add `Bitmap` in the **Data format**.
3. Handle share activation in the App.Xaml.cs by handling the [Application.OnShareTargetActivated event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.onsharetargetactivated?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-application-onsharetargetactivated(windows-applicationmodel-activation-sharetargetactivatedeventargs)).

I've made a simple test about this and you could refer to it. For more information about this, you could also check this document: **[Receive data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/receive-data)**

**Manifest file:**

[image]

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
   protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        ShareOperation shareOperation = args.ShareOperation;
        if (shareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
             var imageStream = await shareOperation.Data.GetBitmapAsync();

            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ShareImagePage), imageStream);

            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
```

**ShareImagePage:**

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Content != null)
        {
            IRandomAccessStreamReference imageReceived = null;

            imageReceived = e.Parameter as IRandomAccessStreamReference;

            using (var imageStream = await imageReceived.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);
                imgImage.Source = bitmapImage;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Very nice!! I tried and it works *almost* perfectly. The only problem I have is that if my app is already running, the share operation creates a new window that is stuck on the splash screen. Is there way to dismiss such window?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi It is expected to open a new window, this is the default behavior when the UWP app receives share data. But if it is stuck on the new window, there should be some issue with the data that you are sharing. You could put a breakpoint in the `OnShareTargetActivated` to check if the data is correctly handled.

Comment: Hi Roy, I followed the method and it completes with no problem (it actually also does what is expected to do in our app...). I just want to dismiss the second window that is opened.

Comment: @CristianoGhersi Why do you want to dismiss the second window that is opened? It is used to receive the data that is shared.  Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: my app can be already opened, and the second window that is opened by the sharing stays there forever...

Comment: @CristianoGhersi Yes, you need to manually close the second window which shows the shared data.

Comment: thanks for the update. Is there any way to programmatically close the second window via C# code? I hope I can do that at the end of the OnShareTargetActivated method, maybe using the input parameter ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs of the method ?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi OK, I got your point. Please try to use  `Window.Current.Close();` in the shared page or in the `OnShareTargetActivated` method.